# Can I slugignore `node_modules`, `tmp` and `storage` folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, slug

I want ways to reduce my slug size, and I was wondering if it will be ok to ignore those folders `/node_modules`, `/storage`, `/tmp`, or will that bring me some issues?

Also, please let me know any other tip you may have to descrease the slug size.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You can remove `node_modules` from your **slug**.

---

But what I acctually did was to add the next build pack **as the last buildpack** in Heroku web site, and it **significantly** reduced my slug size:

- https://github.com/Lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean

[image: Buildpacks]

and also I created a file called `.slug_post_clean` adding a line with **node_modules**.

It is very important to put it as the LAST buildpack, if not, then it won't be very efficient.

Likely you can accomplish the same thing without this buildpack.

Comment: use this commit for the buildpack, otherwise you it won't work because of the owner of the repo added to archive it. I'm adding '#323cc79b69671070d5b51f8795e51d8ff8150a63' to poin to a specific commit. https://github.com/Lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean#323cc79b69671070d5b51f8795e51d8ff8150a63